# Extract adaptive launcher icon from Android apk as svg/png?

Tags: android, vector, icons, apk, extract

Is there a way to extract the launcher icon of an apk file, even if it is an adaptive icon (vector drawable)?
I couldn't find a single batch or python script to achieve this.

There are many scripts which use aapt, but they all just work for png files.

Note: I don't want to run this on the Android device itself.

Comment: I'd love to know this myself.

Comment: Did you find out ? Thanks